# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datagrid'

Tags: fuelux

I am new in programming. I am trying to use sample scripts available in fuelux-master folder to implement it. But  I am unable to use fuelux datagrid in codeigniter.My script shows an error that has no method datagrid. Since I am using sample javascript files so I think this must not be occur.

```
 <script>   
require(['<?php echo(base_url()); ?>fuelux/lib/jquery.js','<?php echo(base_url()); ?>fuelux/sample/data.js','<?php echo(base_url()); ?>fuelux/sample/my_datasource.js', '<?php echo(base_url()); ?>fuelux/sample/datasourceTree.js', '<?php echo(base_url()); ?>fuelux/dist/all.js'], function ($, sampleData, StaticDataSource, DataSourceTree) {

// INITIALIZING THE DATAGRID
var dataSource = new DataSource({
  columns: [
    {
      property: 'employee_id',
      label: 'Employee ID',
      sortable: true
    },
    {
      property: 'punch_date',
      label: 'Date',
      sortable: true
    },
    {
      property: 'punch_time',
      label: 'Punch Time',
      sortable: true
    },
    {
      property: 'punch_in_user_time',
      label: 'Punch In',
      sortable: true
    },
    {
      property: 'punch_out_user_time',
      label: 'Punch Out',
      sortable: true
    } 
  ],
   data:jsObject,

  delay:300
});

$('#MyGrid').datagrid({
  dataSource: dataSource
});

$('#datagrid-reload').on('click', function () {
  $('#MyGrid').datagrid('reload');
});

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is all of your code or not, but the above can't work correctly as you are trying to create a new instance of Datasource when that constructor is not defined. You'd want to use StaticDataSource.

However, it also seems like you might not be pulling in jquery correctly - have you verified that those files you require actually load? Your code seems to be a mix of files from different versions of the packaged release version. Can you provide a URL to a public page so I can help you debug?

Comment: requirejs.config({
   paths: {
    'jquery': 'lib/jquery',
    'underscore': 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min',
    'bootstrap': 'lib/bootstrap/js',
    'fuelux': 'src'
   }
  });

  require(['jquery','sample/my_datasource', 'sample/datasourceTree', 'fuelux/all'], function ($, sampleData, StaticDataSource, DataSourceTree) {}   Can explain these line of codes( used in fuelux) for me

Comment: Sure, that shows usage of RequireJS to load dependencies for the sample page.  If you're not using RequireJS you can find a simpler integration method at https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/wiki/Using-Fuel-UX